# Product of arithmetic progressions

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Let $(a_1,a_2\ldots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ be two permutations of arithmetic progressions of natural numbers. For which $n$ is it possible that $(a_1b_1,a_2b_2,\dots,a_nb_n)$ is an arithmetic progression?

The sequence is (trivially) an arithmetic progression when $n=1$ or $2$. We can notice that $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ cannot be in identical order, since that would mean they both have to be increasing or decreasing, but then the differences of the resulting product terms cannot be constant.

Comment: 11,5,8 and 2,3,1 work for n=3

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312896/product-of-arithmetic-progressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My computer found these for 4, 5 and 6: 
$$A: 1×10, 11×4, 6×13, 16×7\\
B: 8×4, 6×9, 4×19, 7×14, 5×24\\
C: 7×35, 31×11,19×23,13×41,37×17,25×29$$

Comment: $4×41,6×31,8×26,5×46,7×36$